# CheckboxList no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou precisando criar uma checkboxlist na minha pagina utilizando MVC (Razor). Reparei que não existe nenhum Html helper do tipo Html.CheckboxlistFor ou coisa parecida.

Alguém tem algum exemplo de como eu poderia fazer isso. Se possível mostrar como seria o código no controller nas acoes para popular e depois para capturar os checkbox selecionados?

Comment: Eduardo, tem uma outra biblioteca chamada ASP.net Awesome, que é excelente também. [Aqui o link direto para o componente de CheckBoxList](http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/AjaxCheckBoxListDemo/Index). Espero que tenha te ajudado ! [Aqui outro link mais direto de como usar o componente](http://aspnetawesome.com/learn/mvc/AjaxCheckboxList)

Comment: Show de bola mesmo Erik, muitos componentes legais nessa biblioteca! Valeu pela dica!

Comment: Cara, ela é muito massa. Eu usei o lookup e nossa, é muito top !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe um package chamado `MvcCheckBoxList` (cujo helper se chama `CheckBoxListFor`):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC-4

Exemplos de códigos estão no link (mas é bom reproduzir alguma coisa):

**View em Razor**

```
@using MvcCheckBoxList.Model
@model CheckBoxListForApp.Models.FruitViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<section class="checkBoxListFor">
    <p>
        <label>Please Select Fruits:</label>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedFruits.FruitIds,
                                  model => model.AvailableFruits,
                                  fruit => fruit.Id,
                                  fruit => fruit.Name,
                                  model => model.SelectedFruits,
                                  Position.Horizontal)
            <input class="green" type="submit" 
                      value="POST to Controller" />
        }
    </p>
</section>
```

Argumentos:

- Primeiro: Quais Id's serão mandados para o Controller no POST;
- Segundo: As opções disponíveis;
- Terceiro: Qual campo do objeto de dados é considerado Id;
- Quarto: Qual campo do objeto de dados é considerado descrição da Checkbox;
- Quinto: Uma lista de opções que já foram marcadas (montar no Controller);
- Sexto: A orientação da `CheckBoxList` (horizontal ou vertical).

NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcCheckBoxList/

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do @MatheusBessa funciona para um checkbox. Para uma lista, você precisa utilizar a estrutura de mapeamento para um array. Veja o que muda:

A view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxList[0]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxList[1]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxList[2]" />
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxList[n]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

E o controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(String[] CheckboxList)
{
    ...
}
```

É natural que seu viewmodel tenha mais informações. Necessa caso, esse array seria uma property do viewmodel.

É importante destacar que os índices precisam ser sequenciais e iniciados em 0. Se isso não for respeitado, o model binder não irá aceitar como um enumerador.

Como o @MatheusBessa comentou, um checkbox marcado dará a string on. Qualquer coisa diferente disso representa o checkbox limpo.

Comment: Se quiser outro valor além de "on", você pode definir o atributo `value` do checkbox para o desejado, como por exemplo um ID ou texto específico.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar isso.

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="exemplo" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(String exemplo)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Se estiver checado ele retornará **on**, senão ele retornará **null**.

Comment: Com uma checkbox, da para utilizar o Html.CheckboxFor, e eh tranquilo, o problema eh quando eu tenho por exemplo uma lista de categorias e quero que o usuário escolha uma ou mais opções, então terei múltiplos checkboxes.