# Asp.NET MVC bind de checkbox list com valor de string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma lista de checkboxes e preciso bindar os valores que são strings (@item.SelectedValue) com a minha IEnumerable>.

```
 <div class="editor-field perfil-filtro-expander-todasAcoes">
        <div class="metro perfil-filtro-expander-overflow todasAcoes" id="todasAcoes" name="todasAcoes">
            @foreach (DetailedLookupModel<string> item in (IEnumerable<DetailedLookupModel<string>>)ViewBag.Acoes)
            {                    
                <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    @*<input id="@item.SelectedValue" type="checkbox" name="@item" value="@item.SelectedValue"/>*@
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Acoes, new { @type = "checkbox", @id = item.SelectedValue, @value = item.SelectedValue})
                    <label for="@item.SelectedValue">
                        <b>@item.Title</b>
                        <br />
                        <span class="perfil-filtro-expander-descricao">
                            @item.Description
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao)
    </div>
```

Propriedade do Model:

```
[DisplayName("Ações")]
[Required]
public IEnumerable<DetailedLookupModel<String>> Acoes { get; set; }
```

Desta forma eu consigo pegar os checboxes, porém o valor deles que era para ser o `"value"` vem todos `null`. Também não posso realizar alterações dos labels, pois o meu css depende daqueles `ids` para entender quais são os labels para os devidos campos.

Comment: [Já viu isso aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6180/2999)?

Comment: Pior que já, até tentei usar mas encontrei alguns impecilhos, não seria legal eu ter de alterar a arquitetura para ter a lista de itens selecionados sendo que consigo obtela através de uma viewbag com um retorno do banco. Também o campo "title" do helper só aceita um dado, eu precisava estilizar esse valor com meu css como já fiz ali. Alguma solução que vc conheça alternativa?

Comment: Entra aqui: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25342/c-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É um caso clássico do [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/).

Faça o seguinte:

```
<div class="editor-field perfil-filtro-expander-todasAcoes">
    <div class="metro perfil-filtro-expander-overflow todasAcoes" id="todasAcoes" name="todasAcoes">
        @foreach (DetailedLookupModel<string> item in (IEnumerable<DetailedLookupModel<string>>)ViewBag.Acoes)
        {                    
            @Html.Partial("_Acoes", item)
        }
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao)
</div>
```

## `_Acoes.cshtml`

```
@model DetailedLookupModel<String>

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Acoes"))
{
    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Acoes, new { @type = "checkbox", @id = item.SelectedValue, @value = item.SelectedValue})
                <label for="@item.SelectedValue">
                    <b>@item.Title</b>
                    <br />
                    <span class="perfil-filtro-expander-descricao">
                        @item.Description
                    </span>
                </label>
        </div>
}
```