# Controller pegar lista de checkBox de uma view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma *PartialView* onde carrego uma lista de meu objeto e coloquei um *checkbox* para o usuário poder marcar qual item da lista ele quer salvar, portanto não sei como o *controller* pode "saber" qual *check* está marcado na *view*, lembrando que coloquei um *check* manual, que não é uma propriedade da minha *viewmodel*.

Comment: Dê mais datalhes para que possamos te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ..., lembrando que coloquei um *check* manual, que não é uma propriedade da minha *viewmodel*.

Isto não faz muito sentido. De fato, não tem como o *Controller* adivinhar o que você selecionou em tela. Você precisa passar para o *Controller* um modelo de dados que admita *CheckBoxes*.

[Eu já respondi a uma pergunta muito semelhante há algum tempo atrás](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6180/2999), usando um pacote específico para criar *CheckBoxes*. Faltou apenas apontar um bom exemplo de *Binding*, o qual faço abaixo:

Model:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.ViewModels
{
    public class PostedFruitsViewModel
    {
        public string[] FruitIds { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PostedFruits postedFruits)
    {
        // Os Ids de Fruits selecionados estarão em postedFruits.FruitIds.
    }
```